# CSS Resizing and Position Issues

Tags: css, background

This is driving me crazy! I need assistance with this CSS code, please. I have used HTML in the past but I need to use CSS for this layout and I have never used it before. My issue right now is that the top header will not align with the lower image. I can change the margin and everything moves! If I change the size of the picture, it still will not align. Also, when I resize my browser the background moves with it and I need it fixed so the "table" stays in the middle of it. Can you please help?

CSS:

```
html {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

body {
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
line-height:18px;
font-size:12px;
color: #06185c;
background: #ffffff url(crysbg.png) no-repeat top center fixed;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position: absolute;

}

p {
margin: 10px;
padding: 0;
}

h1, h2, h3 {
display:none;
}
.page-wrapper {
margin: auto;
width:auto;
background:url(topbanner.png) no-repeat top center;
position:absolute;
margin-left: 318px;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body id="crystal-self-acceptance">
<div class="page-wrapper">
```

Images of the issue:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vd3Tx.jpg
positioning issue.

i.imgur.com/3EUEYnr.jpg
When the window is resized the center area moves away from the background. (this includes wide screens, just no screenshot of that).

Any help, please?

Edited to add jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Q3y36/8/

Comment: remove `margin-left: 318px` and change it to `auto`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried. It just centered it a bit. Same issue with the position (and background of course).

Comment: Also, that moved the whole table to the left when I want it center. Even all the way left the positioning issue was the same.

Comment: Create JSFIddle or post your full code.

Comment: Ultimately, the error is gonna track down to your use of absolute positioning. Any particular reason you are using absolute?

Comment: Mostly because I don't know what I am doing? The client I am working for wants all CSS. I am used to HTML and using CSS for links and text. Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Q3y36/8/